# Nesting child routes within another child route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**EDIT**

My Initial question included routes with split points, but I've reduced it to the most simple use case of just nesting child routes under each other.

For reference I'm using [the popular react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) and I'm trying to add a simple wrapper component to my routes like so:

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
      path: '/',
      component: CoreLayout,
      indexRoute: Home,
      childRoutes: [{
        component: TransitionWrapper,
        childRoutes: [
          CounterRoute(store)
          ]
      }]
    })
```

but I get the following error and my child routes aren't being rendered:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `children` was not specified in `CoreLayout`.
    in CoreLayout (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router (created by AppContainer)
    in div (created by AppContainer)
    in Provider (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

So basically if I nest child routes in a child route I get a complaint about missing children.

Here is the full setup:

main.js

```
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('root')

let render = () => {
  const routes = require('./routes/index').default(store)

  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer
      store={store}
      history={history}
      routes={routes}
    />,
    MOUNT_NODE
  )
}
```

/routes/index.js

```
import CoreLayout from '../layouts/CoreLayout/CoreLayout'
import Home from './Home'
import NestedChild from './NestedChild'
import TransitionWrapper from './TransitionWrapper'

export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path: '/',
  component: CoreLayout,
  indexRoute: Home,
  childRoutes: [{
    component: TransitionWrapper,
    childRoutes: [
      NestedChild
      ]
  }]
})
```

AppContainer.js

```
class AppContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    routes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render () {
    const { history, routes, store } = this.props

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
          <Router history={history} children={routes} />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default AppContainer
```

CoreLayout.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../../components/Header'
import classes from './CoreLayout.scss'
import '../../styles/core.scss'

export const CoreLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <div className='container text-center'>
    <Header />
    <div className={classes.mainContainer}>
      {children}
    </div>
  </div>
)

CoreLayout.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.element.isRequired
}

export default CoreLayout
```

TransitionWrappper.js <--- IS NOT RENDERING

```
const TransitionWrapper = (props) => (

  <div className="im-not-working">
    {this.props.children}

  </div>
)

export default TransitionWrapper
```

NestedChild.js <--- IS NOT RENDERING

Comment: Please try using "export default Component" might solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just removing `isRequired` from the `children` prop of `CoreLayout`?

If you are loading your child components dynamically, there will be a period of time where the `CoreLayout` renders before you've got child components to put in it.

Comment: when you tried that, what component was giving you the error?  Because CoreLayout wouldn't be giving the error anymore...

Comment: So after a few checks I'm pretty sure that's not it, you can see my newest edit.

Comment: The main point is of course not the complaint about the props but the fact that the child routes aren't being rendered.